# How to get plain String as Retrofit response which I can use with RxAndroid?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-android

I am using Retrofit with RxAndroid
I want to get plain text /String I know I can have Call
but I need to combine it with RxAndroid, How can I do it Single doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RxJava adapter for retrofit:
https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2
And then your call will be something like that:

```
@GET("your/api/url")
Observable<String> getSomeSimpleString(@Query("param") String yourParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Single as if you are not making multiple request.

```
  You can define your interface something like this 

  @GET("/<Url>")
  Single<Response> makeRequest(@Query("parameter") <Parameter>);
```

You call the retrofit api service something like this.

```
          <RetrofitService>makeRequest(String parameter).subscribe(new 
             SingleObserver<String>() {
                      @Override
                      public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                      }

                      @Override
                      public void onSuccess(String response) {

                      }

                      @Override
                      public void onError(Throwable e) {

                      }
                  });
```